# Using an 'if and only if' rule to prove an 'if' statement (in Isabelle)

Tags: logic, isabelle

I am trying to use a limited set of rules to prove a lemma in Isabelle using the `apply` method. This set of rules contains `disj_not1` which is `(P --> Q) = (\<not> P \/ Q)`.

I had the subgoal `(P --> Q) ==> (\<not> P \/ Q)`, so I thought 'Aha! Here is a place for me to use my rule `disj_not1`'. But unfortunately, `disj_not1` is an 'if and only if' rule not an 'if' rule, and Isabelle objects. Yet the 'if and only if' rule should be enough to prove it (more than enough really). Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `subst` method. `apply (subst foo)` will apply an equational rule by rewriting the first instance of the left-hand side of the rule in the goal with the corresponding instance of the right-hand side. You can specify other occurrences with `subst (2 3)` e.g. to rewrite the second and third occurrence. In order to rewrite in the assumptions of the current goal, you need to do `subst (asm)`. To rewrite the second occurrence in an assumption, write `subst (asm) (2)`.

Answer (score 1):

What I sometimes do in such situations is to create the required rule in an ad hoc fashion as follows:

```
apply (rule disj_not1 [THEN iffD1])
```

where `iffD1` is the fact

```
?Q = ?P ⟹ ?Q ⟹ ?P
```

If you need the direction from right to left, you can use `iffD2` instead.